# 'OsmAndCore/QtExtensions.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, openstreetmap, osmand

I tried building the project from https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-ios.git
I get this issue `'OsmAndCore/QtExtensions.h' file not found`[image]

What's the step or package am I missing? how do I make this project work ?

Comment: Did you follow these steps? https://docs.osmand.net/en/main@latest/development/build-osmand/how-to-compile-the-ios-version
Did you take a look at similar errors in the OsmAnd bug tracker at GitHub? https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-iOS/search?q=QtExtensions.h&type=issues

Comment: @scai yes followed all the steps, still no luck.

Comment: Then I guess it would be the best to create a new ticket at https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-iOS/issues

Comment: @scai Thanks, I am trying to build an offline based map application which includes turn by turn navigation and directions on iOS. is OSM the right framework or there are others to look out ? such as MapBox, HereMaps etc.

Comment: OSM is not a framework, OSM is a free geographic database. Did you mean OsmAnd? Anyway, there are various solutions. I can't tell you which one fits your project best. MapBox also uses OSM data (among other sources), btw.

Comment: @scai I successfully ran the project. my requirement is that I need offline maps and used MapBox to achieve that, but I was also looking for Turn-by-turn navigation in offline mode checked MapBox but I couldn't find any.